# facing problem while using provider in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have two screeens

First screen showing all accounts

second screen showing perticular account of selected from first screen

here,in second screen, i am editing name of account...but does not refresh while its effect work properly in first screen...

Whats wrong with my provider concept....

first screen showing all account

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = Provider.of<AppProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: provider.getAllAccounts.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final acc=provider.getAllAccounts[index];
            return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context)
                      .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                    return ShowAccountScreen(account: acc);
                  }));
                },
                title: Text(acc.name),
              ),
            );
          }),

    );
  }
```

second screen for selected account  where i have taken iconbutton for editing

```
class ShowAccountScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Account account;
  ShowAccountScreen({Key? key, required this.account}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ShowAccountScreen> createState() => _ShowAccountScreenState();
}

class _ShowAccountScreenState extends State<ShowAccountScreen> {
  TextEditingController txtname = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = Provider.of<AppProvider>(context,);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.account.name),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                          title: Text('Enter new name'),
                          content: TextField(
                            controller: txtname,
                          ),
                          actions: [
                            TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Account temp = Account(
                                      id: widget.account.id.toString(),
                                      name: txtname.text,);

                                  provider.updateAccount(temp);
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                },
                                child: Text('Change'))
                          ],
                        );
                      });
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.edit))
          ],
        ),
        body: null,

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is provider class

```
class AppProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Account> _accountlist = [
    Account(id: '1', name: 'A'),
    Account(id: '11', name: 'B'),
  ];

  List<Account> get getAllAccounts {
    return _accountlist;
  }

  void updateAccount(Account account) {
    for (int x = 0; x < _accountlist.length; x++) {
      if (_accountlist[x].id == account.id) {
        _accountlist[x] = account;
      }
    }

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

i am editting name in second screen...so here i want to see changes of name in appbar

Answer (score 0):

because on updating name, your build method is not rebuilding itself.

wrap your ListView builder with **Consumer** and by doing this on every update your list view widget will rebuild itself:

```
body: Consumer<AppProvider>(
    builder: (context, provider, child) {
      return YourListViewWidget();
    },
  ),
```

Do it same for the second screen **AppBar**.